# Stripe payment Error using evn variables react.js node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

im trying to use stripe.charges  like this

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_KEY);

router.post("/payment", (req, res) => {
  stripe.charges.create(
    {
      source: req.body.tokenId,
      amount: req.body.amount,
      currency: "usd",
    },
    (stripeErr, stripeRes) => {
      if (stripeErr) {
        res.status(500).json(stripeErr);
      } else {
        res.status(200).json(stripeRes);
      }
    }
  );
});

module.exports = router;
```

but its giving me an error when i call the api from my client:
"You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY"

now  if i change  the stripe object and use the key string directly insted of (process.env.STRIPE_KEY) like

```
 const stripe = require("stripe")("KEYSTRING GOS HERE")
```

it works the way i want to but i dont think i should put my KEY there

i checked my .env filed and the env variable is called STRIPE_KEY there

Comment: what happens when you `console.log(process.env.STRIPE_KEY)` ? did you use `dotenv` to load env ? This is nothing got to do with stripe, and simply whether you load your env

Comment: when i console.log(process.env.STRIPE_KEY) it gives me my stripe key and for the sencond question no how do i do that?

Comment: did you use dotenv? can u google dotenv? How did you load your env? Can you do the console.log before you require stripe?

Comment: yeah in my index.js file i used   const dotenv = require("dotenv"); dotenv.config(); to load env and i can console.log my stripe kye

Comment: i just tried to log process.env.STRIPE_KEY before  require stripe and it gives me undefined

Comment: Soved the problem by  puting const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config(); at the very start of my index.js file before it was after some other imports

Answer (score 2):

Use

```js
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_KEY);
```

under

```js
const dotenv = require("dotenv"); 
 dotenv.config();
```

It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Soved the problem by puting:

```
 const dotenv = require("dotenv"); 
 dotenv.config();
```

at the very start of my index.js file before it was after some other imports

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem although I had imported and configured `dotenv` in my root index.js file like this

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

So what I did basically in order to solve the problem is that I did the exact same configuration of `dotenv` inside my controllers file like this

```
require('dotenv').config();

const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

const prices = async (req, res) => {

    const prices = await stripe.products.list();

    res.json(prices.data);

};


export { prices };
```

and then, everything worked fine as expected.